# Find and classify all extrema for the function $f(x,y)=ye^{x}-e^y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

After differentiating I got
$$f_x=ye^x$$
$$f_y=e^x-e^y$$

Setting them both equal to zero would imply x=0 and x=y; does that mean that (0,0) is the critical point? Sorry if this question seems trivial.

Comment: Indeed, $(0,0)$ is the only critical point. However, the reasoning to get there is that the first equation implies $y=0$. Then the second equation implies $y=x=0$. I'm sure not how you arrived at $x=0$ as the first implication.

Comment: @zugzug Typo. I had meant to type y=0. Thanks for the confirmation.